# Webmin 1.890 fails on require ACL

Tags: webmin, virtualmin

I have problems with Webmin. It was upgraded, nothing changed in configuration, and after the upgrade I cannot do anything, I always get similar errors like following:

```
Require acl/acl-lib.pl failed :
Died at (eval 211) line 1.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall helped after all:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.930_all.deb
dpkg --install webmin_1.930_all.deb
```

There was missing package `unzip`

M.